# Foreach is Skipping all row util the last one

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this little script that I created for my own fun. ( don't ask what is it purpose )

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
include("PostalCodeAr.php");
$MultiDimensionAr['K'][0]['A'][1]['M'][0] = "ON";
echo count($PostalCodeArray)."\n";
foreach($PostalCodeArray as $Postal => $Code);
{
    echo $Postal."\n";
    $Postal = strtoupper($Postal);
    $MultiDimensionAr[$Postal{0}][$Postal{1}][$Postal{2}][$Postal{3}][$Postal{4}][$Postal{5}] = $Code;
}
```

And In the file PostalCodeAr.php   there is a very very big array with all postalcode and it'
s province code.

The Output im getting from all this is

```
916760
t1s0k6
```

t1s0k6 is the last one in the array in the file postalCodeAr.php

So Technically if the function count()  is correctly outputing the correct amount of row why the foreach is it not running through them all?

Comment: Using a 6 dimension array to contain your postal codes is a weird and terrible way of containing that data.

Comment: Well in the foreach there is a echo $postal and Im runing the php script in cgi so there is no buffer

Comment: @Adam Yeah i Know that is why I said Im doing this just for fun I wanted to try something wierd. and perhaps faster to actualy load  since when using an normal array it take forever to go through but in a multi dimensinal i thing i could be faster since i only need to check if the postal is there and if it is i need it's province code.   so I only need an if(isset()) and then if it is true i take it's value.

Comment: Your PHP is a bit sloppy, so I'm going to guess your array is borked. Use print_r() on the array to verify its structure.

Comment: I would repair the title on this post, but it feels a bit like expressing approval.

Comment: @Smandoli Your right there is nothing wierd here now,.  Just a simple error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It shouldn't be a semicolon after foreach.

foreach executes a block or a statement multiple times.
The semicolon gives it an empty statement, and the block
is simply ignored. Due to the nature or phps foreach the
iteration variables are still in scope even after the
last iteration, so that's why one row is echoed.